Calling Filter Encoding Specification function Centroid breaks on error while making WFS request
I'm trying to include centroid data in WFS response by utilizing Filter Encoding Specification(FES) function called Centroid.
/geoserver/wfs?service=wfs&version=2.0.0&request=getFeature&typenames=officialareas&cql_filter=CATEGORY in ('07','08','09')&resultType=results(Centroid(features))

API states that it supports this function but results in error:
Failed to set property RESULTTYPE in request object using value results(centroid(features)) of type class java.lang.String class java.lang.String cannot be cast to class net.opengis.wfs20.ResultTypeType

Compared to other APIs I can see that in this configuration the parameter/argument for the function is defined as xs:string
<fes:Function name="Centroid">
<fes:Returns>xs:string</fes:Returns>
<fes:Arguments>
<fes:Argument name="features">
<fes:Type>xs:string</fes:Type>
</fes:Argument>
</fes:Arguments>
</fes:Function>

However in other APIs it is defined as gml:AbstractGeometryType
<fes:Function name="centroid">
<fes:Returns>xs:string</fes:Returns>
<fes:Arguments>
<fes:Argument name="geometry">
<fes:Type>gml:AbstractGeometryType</fes:Type>
</fes:Argument>
</fes:Arguments>
</fes:Function>

Of course string is "same" as gml:AbstractGeometryType but maybe in heavily typed environment this can cause the error?

can you please add your actual request and the log file relevant to the error message

Added request but don't have access to log file

do you have a reference that shows using a function in the resultType I've never seen that before
